# Handling Contracts extension and licensing/Subscriptions addition/removal in dimensional model

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, star-schema-datawarehouse

Background: I am trying to design a star schema for a data warehouse. We have the following business model where we have few products that our customers can buy and then use. The customers are companies and then they have people in their organization who can be mapped to the licenses they have brought for products.

I have the following dimensions.

Account_dim: The dimension contains all the list of companies that have are our current/prospective with our company. It could have companies who still don't have a contract with us and are still in a discussion phase. so some rows might not have a contract.

User_dim: This is the list of users the company has nominated point of contacts for their company. So a user will belong to one particular Account in the Account_dim. One account can have many users.

Product_Dim: This dimension contains all the information regarding all the products we sell. The cost of a license and how many users are allowed on a license.So if for example he brought product A a max of two users can use it.

Now I have three tables that have data regarding the contract.

Contract: It contains information regarding a contract we have which will include the contract start date and end date and the account which this contract is assigned to.

products_bought: This table contains the product brought under a contract. A contract can hold multiple products bought.Each product row will have the product start date/end date and the price of the asset the client has paid.

allocated users:Each product bought can have users mapped to it who are allowed to use the product which is the user in user_dim for that account. Basically attaching a license to a user.

I am trying to model the contract, product bought and allocated user so I can generate the following data.

1. The amount of money a account has spend on products.
2. THe utilization of licenses by an account. for example an account has a product that allows 3 users but has only one user mapped to it will show the product is under utilized.

I tried denormalizing all three tables into one fact table but the I am running into problem where the contract end date can be changed if it is extended. As well as new assets can be mapped to it. Also last be not least, the company can remove a user and then map another user to the product or remove users because they left the company or add more users.

How can this be best modeled. Because they contract and asset users can change they should be SCDs rather than fact table or how should I implement a fact to handle these changes as well which must be captured as well to maintain history of usage over time.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to read a book on how to go about designing a data warehouse: [The Data Warehouse Lifecycle Toolkit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Lifecycle-Toolkit-2nd/dp/0470149779/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=ralph%20kimball&qid=1605529380&sr=8-4) as this will give you all the information you need to be able to answer questions like this.

However, to specifically address your question, the best way to approach this is as follows:

1. Define your measures: what are the values that you wish to be able to aggregate in your reports
2. Define the grain of each measure: what are the dimensions that uniquely identify each measure. For example, a transaction amount might be defined by Store, Customer and Date/Time; if you dropped any of these then the transaction amount would change; if you added another dimension, such as rainfall, it would not change the transaction amount (n.b. having defined the grain of a measure you should never add dimensions that would change the grain e.g. Product Dimension, in this example)

Once you have defined your measures and their grains you can add all the other dimensions to them (that won't affect their grain) andn then decide whether to hold them in separate fact tables or combine them into one fact table:

1. Rule: if two measures don't have the same grain you must not put them in the same fact table
2. Guidance: for measures that meet the above rule, if there is also significant overlap in the other dimensions you want to use for each measure then consider combining them into a single fact table. My rule of thumb is that if you have 2-3 dimensions that don't apply to all measures then that's OK; if you hit 5 or more then you probably need to be thinking of splitting the measures into separate facts